# Cannot pass data into the controller in ng-bind in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have used ng-blur and pass data using a function and I couldnot print the value by using console.log in the controller

test.template.html

```
<div class="col-value">
    <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" style=' box-sizing: border-box; width:50%' ng-blur="saveData()" ng-model="value">%
</div>
```

test.controller.js

```
$scope.saveData = function(){

  console.log($scope.value);

  };
```

Can someone kindly help me to solve this issue? Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This, pass the ng-model value inside ng-blur="saveData(value)" function.

```
<div class="col-value">
    <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" style=' box-sizing: border-box; width:50%' ng-blur="saveData(value)" ng-model="value">%
</div>

$scope.saveData = function(value){

  console.log(value);

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. Compare the below code snippet with your code.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.saveData = function(){

  console.log($scope.value);

  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body  ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div class="col-value">
    <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" style=' box-sizing: border-box; width:50%' ng-blur="saveData()" ng-model="value">%
</div>
  </body>
```